# How are enum fields with a function as data provider defined in fields_meta_data?

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

So i have a custom enum which has a function as data provider:

```
$dictionary['Opportunity']['fields']['custom_enum_c'] = array(
    'labelValue' => 'Enum',
    'name' => 'custom_enum_c',
    'inline_edit'  => '1',
    'vname' => 'LBL_CUSTOM_ENUM',
    'type' => 'enum',
    'function' => 'getAccounts',
    'len' => '255',
    'comment' => 'Enum',
    'default_value' => '',
);
```

How is this field saved in fields_meta_data? Specifically where is the function saved in the fields_meta_data table? In one of the ext fields?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As far as I can see the `function` attribute of fields is not stored in the `fields_meta_data` table at all.
May I ask why you'd need it in there?

Comment: @Jay Just out of interest. if the vardef and metadata files get generated from db. Then the drop down wouldnt work in that case. Or whats the use case for this table?

Comment: what is location of above code and file name?

Comment: your code will not enter anything in database. It will modify cached file of vardef accordingly and SugarCRM will read field definition from there instead of fields_meta_data table.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see that there is no option in studio to enter "function" there. You can only set it via code. Either by creating new field in custom/Extension/modules//Ext/Vardef OR you can override exciting one as well. Let me know if you face any issue while exploring it.